# simple algorithm to calculate and update LLR for nand flash memory?

Tags: maximum-likelihood-estimation

I'm workding on nand flash DSP (Digital Signal Processing) now, and encounter obstacle, which is: how to generate and update Log-Likelihood Ratio (LLR) LUT for Triple- and Quad Level Cell (TLC and QLC) NAND flash memory? any suggestion or reference will be very useful!

I've tried in MLC case, but it performance is poor, maybe the method I'am used is mistake.

Comment: Hello Milin, could you possibly define the acronyms you've used? Many people (including me) are not familiar with all acronyms and some of them may be used differently in different fields.